# Divide MySQL SELECT all into sections of 7 results and run new query on each section

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to divide the results of a MySQL query into groups by dividing the number of results by 7 so that I can then run a query on each group.

I have a table that has entries entered by the user over a period of time.  I intend to calculate how many days the period of time is, divide it by 7 so I have weeks, then run a query on each week.  Eg, how many of a particular value was entered in week 1, then week 2 etc.

The time period will be different every time.

Comment: You can limit the results using limit 7; limit 7, 8; etc or you can use a Group by statement but without more info I can't help you. Tip use modulus operator % to work out the limit numbers.

Comment: Everything is possible.

Comment: Without knowing what you want to achieve, a meaningful answer is not possible.  What exactly do you want to do with the groups of 7?  Why 7 and not 8?  This may be achievable in sql alone, depending on exactly what you seek, but based on the minimal information provided, the best way by far would be to extract your first query results then deal with the chunking and addditional logic in PHP.

Comment: @RobertSeddon-Smith I have edited my question so you know what the relevance of 7 is.  I was going to use php to get the number of queries per weeks, store is in a variable to then use in the MySQL query but that is as far as my logic has got

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to assign a row number to each row, count a maximum number of rows, then divide it by 7 and assign a group number ( from 1 to 7 ) to each row.
Then save results of the query to the temporary table, and query that table for required group number:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE results AS
SELECT ceil( rn / (  @rn/7 )) group_nbr,
       x.*
FROM ( 
   select (@rn:=@rn+1) rn, abc.* 
   from table_name abc, (select @rn:=0) rn
) x;


SELECT *
FROM results
WHERE group_nbr = 4;
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18719/1)